# Pointer Events API and dragging

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-chrome, drag, touch-event

I'm trying to implement mobile-only touch UI using [Pointer Events API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Pointer_events) and this just isn't working:
https://codepen.io/kyrsquir/full/gOrZEoe

The goal is to allow scrolling in the card and dragging the card between expanded and collapsed state within the same UI. I only managed to get dragging by the handle to work in Chrome emulator and iOS Safari. Dragging via card content doesn't work anywhere.

On Android Chrome dragging doesn't work at all.

The weirdest part is that the same UI works everywhere using `touchstart`, `touchmove` and `touchend` events (https://codepen.io/kyrsquir/full/QWNZzav) but performance of `touchmove` in Chrome on Android in the presence of scrollbar is so terrible that I'm trying to reimplement it with pointer events.

Vue component code:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div
      :class="containerClass"
      :style="containerStyle"
      @pointerdown="pointerDownHandler"
      @pointermove="pointerMoveHandler"
      @pointerup="pointerUpHandler"
      @pointerover="reportEvent"
      @pointerenter="reportEvent"
      @pointercancel="reportEvent"
      @pointerout="reportEvent"
      @pointerleave="reportEvent"
      @gotpointercapture="reportEvent"
      @lostpointercapture="reportEvent"
      @transitionend="transitionEndHandler"
      class="card"
    >
      <svg viewBox="0 0 100 20" always-swipeable="true" class="drag-handle">
        <polyline points="27,10 73,10" stroke-linecap="round"></polyline>
      </svg>
      <div class="scrollbox" ref="scrollbox">
        <div :key="item" class="item" v-for="item in items">
          {{ item }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      deltaY: 0,
      isDraggingByHandle: false,
      isTransitioning: false,
      items: [
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5,
        6,
        7,
        8,
        9,
        10,
        11,
        12,
        13,
        14,
        15,
        16,
        17,
        18,
        19,
        20,
      ],
      offsetHeight: 0,
      scrollboxHeight: 0,
      scrollTop: 0,
      touchAction: null,
      verticalStates: [
        {
          translateY: 0,
        },
        {
          translateY: window.innerHeight - 200,
        },
      ],
      verticalStateIndex: 0,
    };
  },

  computed: {
    activeVerticalState() {
      return this.verticalStates[this.verticalStateIndex];
    },
    containerClass() {
      return {
        "show-scrollbar": this.isScrollable,
        transition: this.isTransitioning,
      };
    },
    containerStyle() {
      return {
        transform: `translateY(${this.translateY}px)`,
      };
    },
    isAnySwipeAllowed() {
      return this.isDraggingByHandle || !this.isScrollable;
    },
    isExpanded() {
      return this.verticalStateIndex === 0;
    },
    isScrollable() {
      return this.isExpanded && this.scrollHeight > this.offsetHeight;
    },
    isSwipeDown() {
      return (
        this.deltaY > 0 && (this.isAnySwipeAllowed || this.scrollTop === 0)
      );
    },
    isSwipeUp() {
      return (
        this.deltaY < 0 &&
        (this.isAnySwipeAllowed ||
          this.offsetHeight + this.scrollTop === this.scrollHeight)
      );
    },
    scrollbox() {
      return this.$refs.scrollbox;
    },
    translateY() {
      let translateY = this.activeVerticalState.translateY;
      if (
        this.touchAction === "verticalSwipe" &&
        (this.isSwipeDown || this.isSwipeUp)
      ) {
        translateY = translateY + this.deltaY;
      }
      return translateY;
    },
  },

  mounted() {
    this.updateScrollboxData();
  },

  methods: {
    pointerDownHandler: function ({ clientY, target, pointerId }) {
      console.log("pointerdown", target, pointerId);
      target.setPointerCapture(pointerId);
      this.updateScrollboxData();
      this.isDraggingByHandle = Boolean(
        target.getAttribute("always-swipeable")
      );
      this.touchStartClientY = clientY;
      this.touchAction = "tap";
    },
    pointerMoveHandler: function ({ clientY, target, pointerId }) {
      console.log("pointermove", target, pointerId, this.deltaY);
      this.deltaY = clientY - this.touchStartClientY;
      // promote touchAction to swipe or scroll depending on deltas and other variables
      if (this.touchAction === "tap") {
        if (this.isSwipeDown || this.isSwipeUp) {
          this.touchAction = "verticalSwipe";
        } else {
          this.touchAction = "scroll";
          this.updateScrollboxData();
        }
      }
    },
    pointerUpHandler: function ({ target, pointerId }) {
      console.log("pointerup", target, pointerId);
      target.releasePointerCapture(pointerId);
      switch (this.touchAction) {
        case "tap":
          if (!this.isExpanded) {
            this.verticalStateIndex = Math.max(this.verticalStateIndex - 1, 0);
            this.isTransitioning = true;
          }
          break;
        case "verticalSwipe":
          if (this.isSwipeDown) {
            this.verticalStateIndex = Math.min(
              this.verticalStateIndex + 1,
              this.verticalStates.length - 1
            );
          } else if (this.isSwipeUp) {
            this.verticalStateIndex = Math.max(this.verticalStateIndex - 1, 0);
          }
          this.isTransitioning = true;
          this.deltaY = 0;
          break;
      }
    },
    reportEvent({ type, target, pointerId }) {
      console.log(type, target, pointerId);
    },
    transitionEndHandler() {
      this.touchAction = null;
      this.isTransitioning = false;
      this.updateScrollboxData();
    },
    updateScrollboxData() {
      const { scrollHeight, offsetHeight, scrollTop } = this.scrollbox;
      this.offsetHeight = offsetHeight;
      this.scrollHeight = scrollHeight;
      this.scrollTop = scrollTop;
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 5vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  touch-action: none;

  .card {
    pointer-events: all;
    width: 90vw;
    height: 100%;
    touch-action: none;

    &.transition {
      transition: transform 0.15s ease-out;
    }

    .drag-handle {
      stroke-width: 5px;
      stroke: #bfbfc0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 30px;
      background: pink;
    }

    .scrollbox {
      overflow-y: hidden;
      pointer-events: none;
      background: green;
      height: 85vh;

      .item {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        height: 150px;
        font-size: 36px;
        background: yellow;
      }
    }

    &.show-scrollbar .scrollbox {
      overflow-y: scroll;
      pointer-events: all;
    }
  }
}
</style>
```

Comment: Minimal example please, **minimal**. And even though I didn't check this wall of code, why pointer events instead of simple touch events?

Comment: @Kaiido That's as dehydrated as it gets without losing the whole point of the issue. I removed everything that isn't actually required to show the problem. As stated in the question, I tried touch events approach initially but faced performance issues @Chrome/Android. They're described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63979657)